# Is it possible to prompt a user for a password through a Java dialog from a web application?

Tags: ruby, tomcat, jdbc, jruby, ibm-midrange

The reason I ask is, I have a web application written in Ruby (1.8.7-p357) with the Sinatra Framework (1.3.2). The interpreter is JRuby (1.6.7.2). I am connecting to an AS/400 (System i v6r1) and when I supply the app with an incorrect password for connecting to the database in the code I am prompted with a Java dialog box to supply the proper password.

This works swimmingly on my development machine (Ubuntu 11.10) using WEBrick. However when I deploy the application with the incorrect password the application hangs. Rummaging through the log files shows that the system is waiting for a response from the user with a call to the function: java.awt.Dialog.show().

Here is the relevant portion of the trace:

```
http-8080-2" daemon prio=6 tid=0x03d81400 nid=0x10c in Object.wait() [0x06278000]
java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
- waiting on <0x24a022a8> (a java.awt.Component$AWTTreeLock)
at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:503)
at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport.enter(Unknown Source)
- locked <0x24a022a8> (a java.awt.Component$AWTTreeLock)
at java.awt.Dialog.show(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.as400.access.PasswordDialog.prompt(PasswordDialog.java:284)
at com.ibm.as400.access.ToolboxSignonHandler.handleSignon(ToolboxSignonHandler.java:499)
at com.ibm.as400.access.ToolboxSignonHandler.connectionInitiated(ToolboxSignonHandler.java:50)
at com.ibm.as400.access.AS400.promptSignon(AS400.java:2153)
at com.ibm.as400.access.AS400.signon(AS400.java:3417)
- locked <0x23121378> (a com.ibm.as400.access.AS400)
at com.ibm.as400.access.AS400.connectService(AS400.java:869)
at com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCConnection.setProperties(AS400JDBCConnection.java:3016)
at com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCDriver.prepareConnection(AS400JDBCDriver.java:1242)
at com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCDriver.initializeConnection(AS400JDBCDriver.java:1105)
at com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCDriver.connect(AS400JDBCDriver.java:355)
```

Is it possible for a web application to launch a Java dialog on a client machine in this manner? If so, why is it failing in my deployment environment?

Comment: You'd need a java applet for that, and they're dead. I suppose your code is trying to run a GUI app on a server...

Comment: Hi Tass, the app is a regular Web application and I was in the process of removing the username and password from the connection string prior to deployment when I stumbled upon the prompt. I thought maybe I could just have the user enter their username and pass and let JDBC handle incorrect passwords.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the [IBM Toolbox for Java JDBC property](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/topic/rzahh/jdbcproperties.htm) `prompt` to `false` and catch the exception when the connection fails.

[image]

---

Also it's a good practice to set the Java system property `java.awt.headless=true` when running a server application.

See [Using Headless Mode in the Java SE Platform](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/Desktop/headless/)
.